# Template Toolkit: Extracting a part of a template

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I was assigned the task to rewrite our home-made templates with Perl Template Toolkit.

Our templates have the possibility to extract a fragment of the template (and then make HTML from it) instead of using the entire template.

How to do it with Template Toolkit?

The best solution I came with is the following:

Let we have a template `x.html` with fragment `A`.

The fragment should be extracted into new file. (I am to name it like `x/A.html` for consistency.) In the original template `x.html` it should be replaced with `[% INCLUDE 'x/A.html' %]`. So I could be able to use either the entire template `x.html` or its fragment `x/A.html`. Probably we may have several levels of inclusion like `x/A/B.html`.

Are there other ways to do it? (I don't like to idea to split it in subdirectories as described above, but haven't come up with a better solution.)

Comment: Put things that repeat into smaller subsets. Templates are like functions in that regard. I would not stick them into folders based on where they are (first) used, but in folders according to what they do or what they are for. A _product_ template for example might be used in the cart, on a detail page, and in a newsletter. It should not be subdir to _cart_ just because that's where it initially showed up.

Comment: @simbabque Your answer (well, comment) is not to my question. I have not given the task to restructure the templates and its parts, but just to "translate" from a legacy template "language" into modern Template Toolkit. It is the only task I was assigned. I am not now going to do more restructuring work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking whether there's a better way to extract the fragment from the parent template?

(Answer is: no, that's probably the best way.)

Or are you asking is there a better way to organize the extracted fragements?

(Answer is: no real best answer, everywhere will have their own house style - you aren't going to go too far wrong by picking any convention.)

Most common conventions for naming I've seen are subdirectories `x/A.html` and prefixes `x_A.html`. Whether you use the name of the parent template for `x` or you choose to group by functionality as simbabque suggested is another matter of taste: grouping by functionality scales better on larger and more complicated layouts where you have a great deal of reuse of components, but grouping by use case is conceptually simpler in smaller use cases with little or no component reuse.